# Drawer button toggle not working in native-base

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, native-base

I'm new to swift and i'm trying to toggled the drawer in native base. Opening the drawer works fine, but once clicked the same button it wont toggle (not closing). Code as bellow.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 Dimensions,
 Text,
 View
} from 'react-native';
import { Drawer } from 'native-base';

    export default class App extends Component {
      closeDrawer=()=> {
        this._drawer._root.close()
      };
      openDrawer=()=> {
        this._drawer._root.open()
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <Drawer
            openDrawerOffset={(Dimensions.get('window').width) / 2}
            styles={drawerStyles}
            ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
            content={<MenuBar navigator={this._navigator} />}
             >
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
              <View>
                <Header openDrawerClicked={this.openDrawer}/>
              </View>
           </View>

         </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
const drawerStyles = {
  drawer: { paddingTop: 113, shadowColor: '#000000', shadowOpacity: 0.5, shadowRadius: 3,  paddingBottom:60},
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Share GIF of output for this snippet

Comment: check now its been updated

Comment: include `onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}` with `Drawer`

Comment: still the same effect no difference. Hence even in context to my original code upon tap of the view the drawer get close

Comment: what is the version of NativeBase you are using here? Also which navigation?

Comment: i think its a layout issue which i cant find, cuz if i set the " side='right' ", it does open from right side and works the toggle fine perfectly

Comment: found the issue. Is there a way to topOffset property, bcz a transparent view lays on top of my menu button itseems